# 3sum algorithm. I am not getting results for numbers less than the target

Tags: python, arrays, while-loop, return, conditional-statements

How can I get this to print all triplets that have a sum less than or equal to a target? Currently this returns triplets that are = to the target. I've tried to change and think but can't figure out

```py
def triplets(nums):
    # Sort array first
    nums.sort()
    output = []

    # We use -2 because at this point the left and right pointers will be at same index
    # For example [1,2,3,4,5] current index is 4 and left and right pointer will be at 5, so we know we cant have a triplet
    #       _ LR
    for i in range(len(nums) - 2):

        # check if current index and index -1 are same if same continue because we need distinct results
        if i > 0 and nums[i] == nums[i - 1]:
            continue

        left = i + 1
        right = len(nums) - 1

        while left < right:

            currentSum = nums[i] + nums[left] + nums[right]

            if currentSum <= 8:
                output.append([nums[i], nums[left], nums[right]])
                # below checks again to make sure index isnt same with adjacent index
                while left < right and nums[left] == nums[left + 1]:
                    left += 1
                while left < right and nums[right] == nums[right - 1]:
                    right -= 1
                # In this case we have to change both pointers since we found a solution
                left += 1
                right -= 1
            elif currentSum > 8:
                left += 1

            else:
                right -= 1

        return output
```

So for example input array is `[1,2,3,4,5]` we will get the result (1,2,3),(1,2,4),(1,2,5),(1,3,4) Because these have a sum of less than or equal to target of 8.

Comment: What do you mean 'both' triplets? Please give at least one example input with actual vs desired output. Is target always 8?

Comment: My bad that was definitely confusing. I meant triplets that have the sum of <= 8. So for example input array is [1,2,3,4,5] we will get the result (1,2,3),(1,2,4),(1,2,5),(1,3,4) Because these have a sum of less than or equal to target of 8

Comment: Your algorithm is not easy to understand for me, I can't find the error quickly. I recommend you check that the overall algorithm is correct, then that your implementation is correct (maybe using a debugger).

Answer (score 0):

The main barrier to small changes to your code to solve the new problem is that your original goal of outputting all distinct triplets with `sum == target` can be solved in `O(n^2)` time using two loops, as in your algorithm. The size of the output can be of size proportional to `n^2`, so this is optimal in a certain sense.

The problem of outputting all distinct triplets with `sum <= target`, cannot always be solved in `O(n^2)` time, since the output can have size proportional to `n^3`; for example, with an array `nums = [1,2,...,n], target = n^2 + 1`, the answer is all possible triples of elements. So your algorithm has to change in a way equivalent to adding a third loop.

One `O(n^3)` solution is shown below. Being a bit more clever about filtering duplicate elements (like using a hashmap and working with frequencies), this should be improvable to `O(max(n^2, H))` where `H` is the size of your output.

```py
def triplets(nums, target=8):
    nums.sort()
    output = set()

    for i, first in enumerate(nums[:-2]):

        if first * 3 > target:
            break

        # Filter some distinct results
        if i + 3 < len(nums) and first == nums[i + 3]:
            continue

        for j, second in enumerate(nums[i + 1:], i + 1):
            if first + 2 * second > target:
                break
            if j + 2 < len(nums) and second == nums[j + 2]:
                continue

            for k, third in enumerate(nums[j + 1:], j + 1):
                if first + second + third > target:
                    break
                if k + 1 < len(nums) and third == nums[k + 1]:
                    continue

                output.add((first, second, third))

    return list(map(list, output))
```